# Modulus and squaring

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $P( (X-1)^2 \leq u)$.
How does this become $P( |X-1| \leq \sqrt{u})$ and thus, $P( 1- \sqrt{u} \leq X \leq 1+ \sqrt{u}) $?

Comment: Did you mean **(u)** where you wrote **(s)**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(X-1)^2\le u$

Take the (positive) square root of both sides:

$|X-1|\le \sqrt u$

From the definition of absolute value:

$-\sqrt u \le X-1$ and $X-1\le\sqrt u$

Add $1$ to both sides:

$1-\sqrt u\le X$ and $X\le 1+\sqrt u$

Comment: Makes sense. Why do we only take the positive square root though? why can we not use the negative square root as well?